# How $x^2$ increases by $x+1/x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I was going through one of the topic "Introduction to Formal proof". In one example while explaining "Hypothesis" and "conclusion" got confused.

The example is as follows:

> If $x\geq4$, then $2^x \geq x^2$.

While deriving conclusion article said "As $x$ grows larger than $4$, LHS $2^x$ doubles as $x$ increases by $1$ and RHS grows by ratio $x+1/x$".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is mathematica and a picture is worth a thousand words.

```
 Plot[{2^x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer our specific question, RHS grows by
$$
\frac{x+1)^2}{x^2} =  \frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2} = 1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} < 1 + \frac{2}{x} + \frac{2}{x} = 1+ \frac 1 x < 2$$
since
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} < \frac{2}{x}$$

Ratio is even smaller than $x+1/x$.

Note, there are a lot of ways of showing the inequality as others have pointed out. I am just explaining the growth rate statement.

By the way $x+1/x$ is always greater than $2$ so I don't see the point of the statement in the book.